# Canvas - Creating a partially solid and partially dashed line

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a line in HTML canvas that is part solid and part dashed. Here is my code

```
ctx.moveTo(10,10);
ctx.lineTo(70,70);
ctx.setLineDash([5,15]);
ctx.lineTo(100,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

However this draws the entire line solid. I tried to add setLineDash before I drew the final line segment but that didn't work. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`setLineDash` will apply for the whole path.

Either create a new Path by calling

```
//yourfirstLine();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath()
//yourSecondLine();
```

```js
var ctx =  c.getContext('2d')
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(10,10);
ctx.lineTo(70,70);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.setLineDash([5,15]);
ctx.moveTo(80,80);
ctx.lineTo(100,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

or calculate the `dashArray` accordingly : 
(here for the same result, it would be `ctx.setLineDash([85,15,30])`).

```js
var ctx =  c.getContext('2d')
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.setLineDash([85,15,30]);
ctx.moveTo(10,10);
ctx.lineTo(70,70);
ctx.lineTo(100,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Personnaly, I would go for the former.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this before your code:

```
ctx.setLineDash([1, 5]);
```